# Speeding up Sympy solve() on a particular equation

Tags: python, optimization, sympy, numerical-methods, symbolic-math

I am trying to solve an equation but the `solve()` function is taking over 10 minutes even on a high RAM colab notebook. Are there any simplifications to the problem that I can take to speed this along? Here is the code:

```
x, y, x_0, y_0, x_new, y_new, t, f = symbols('x y x_0 y_0 x_new y_new t f')

D = (2 * (1 - t) * sqrt(x * y) + t * (x + y)) / (2 * (x + y) * sqrt(x * y))

D_old = D.subs([(x, x_0), (y, y_0)])
D_new = D.subs([(x, x_new), (y, y_new)])

delta_D = D_new - D_old

target = Eq(delta_D, f)

answer = solve(target, x_new)
```

Comment: for which variable are you trying to solve `target`?

Comment: I edited the code to show that. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

If it is taking a long time you must be trying to solve for one of the `x` or `y` values. This will require solving a messy cubic equation in many variables. It would be better if you just substituted in the values of interest and then used `nsolve` to find the roots of interest. Otherwise, you can get a symbolic solution to the generic cubic `g3 = solve(a*x**3 + b*x**2 + c*x + d, x)` and then substitute in the corresponding expressions for the coefficients of `collect(sympy.solvers.solvers.unrad(target.rewrite(Add))[0], v)` where `v` is the variable of interest. But I won't bog this down with more details until it is clear what you really want to do.

Comment: I also do not understand what you are recommending with respect to solving for the generic cubic etc.

Comment: Given `xx=solve(a*x + b, x)[0]` and `(e+f+g+h+i)*x + j+k+l+m+n+o+p` you don't have to force the solver to handle the many symbols of the second expression to get a solution for `x` -- you can just use the simpler expression for `xx` to do ``xx.subs(a, e+f+g+h+i).subs(b, j+k+l+m+n+o+p)`. This is a linear example; you can do the same for a cubic expression.